# How to build factory girl association?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm having troubles building association. I have my models defined like this:

```
class Conversation
  belongs_to :user1
  belongs_to :user2
  has_many :messages
end
```

and I've defined these factories

```
factory :user do
  name "name"
end

factory :female, parent: :user do
  gender 'f'
end 

factory :male, parent: :user do
  gender 'm'
end 

factory :message do
  message "message"
  conversation
end
```

Now I'm trying to create factory "conversation_with_messages" like this

```
factory :conversation do
    read false
    association :user1, factory: :male
    association :user2, factory: :female    
    factory :conversation_with_messages do

      ignore do
        messages_count 10
      end

      after(:create) do |conversation, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:message, evaluator.messages_count, author: conversation.user1)
      end
    end
  end
```

but doing `FactoryGirl.create(:conversation_with_messages)` gives database error saying that user1_id column needs to be not null.

I'm wondering why this column isn't filled and what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified the `class_name` in your conversation model relations?

```
class Conversation
  belongs_to :user1, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :user2, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :messages
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When testing is hard, consider modifying your design. Two thoughts spring to mind:

**1) *MUST* `User`s have multiple `Conversation`s?**

If something like Twitter's direct message model (one continuous conversation between any two users) would be acceptable, then you could go for something like:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'

  default_scope order("created_at DESC")

  def read?
    !self.unread?
  end

  def read_or_unread
    self.unread? ? "unread" : "read"
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, foreign_key: :recipient_id

  def messages_grouped_by_sender
    msg_ids = messages.select("MAX(id) AS id").group(:sender_id).collect(&:id)
    Message.includes(:sender).where(id: msg_ids)
  end
end

class Conversation

  THEM_TO_ME = "sender_id = :their_id AND recipient_id = :my_id"
  ME_TO_THEM = "sender_id = :my_id AND recipient_id = :their_id"

  def initialize(me, them)
    @me = me
    @them = them
  end

  def them
    @them
  end

  def thread
    Message.where("#{ME_TO_THEM} OR #{THEM_TO_ME}", ids)
  end

  def unread?
    # Checking only the newest message is good enough
    messages_to_me.first.try(:unread)
  end

  def mark_as_read
    messages_to_me.where(:unread => true).update_all(:unread => false)
  end

  def to_or_from_me(message)
    message.sender == @me ? "From" : "To"
  end

  private

  def messages_to_me
    Message.where(THEM_TO_ME, ids)
  end

  def ids
    { :my_id => @me.id, :their_id => @them.id }
  end
end
```

**2) Do `Conversation`s need to be persisted to the database?**

If `Message` looked like the following then you could initialise a `Conversation` by taking a message then following the chain of previous messages.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :previous_message, class_name: 'Message'
end

class Conversation
  def initialize(message)
    @message = message
  end

  def messages
    //use @message to follow the chain of messages
  end
end
```

Comment: for some reasons I need grouping object that will aggregate messages, and testing itself isn't hard - I just have a problem with creating proper FactoryGirl code for what I think is pretty simple use case.